# Rating for this circuit breaker at 120 voltsAC

Tags: fuses

[Here](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/cb-2802/2-amp-circuit-breaker/1.html) is a circuit breaker rated **2 amps at 32 volts DC** and **2 amps at 250 volts AC**

[image]

What is the amperage it will break at when I apply **120 volts AC**

Answer (score 4):

2 amps.

Voltage ratings for switches and breakers are specified as the maximum the device can operate safely at without causing arc fault or breaking down.

DC and AC are different in that the make/break operation is different: in short, because AC crosses zero-voltage, the switch or breaker can do so with less arc.

So, in summary, you can use this breaker and expect it to trip at 2 amps, but don't exceed its 250 volt AC rating.

Comment: Thanks, so that should also mean that I should not exceed the 32 volt DC rating? That seems like a very low voltage to cause arcing.

Comment: When the breaker trips, there is a moment where the contacts are very close together, and the air gap is very small. The arc will be small and short-lived, but it will deteriorate the internal contacts somewhat. Repeat this enough, and you'll have a useless breaker that might no longer trip at the rated current (read: unsafe).

Comment: @skyler The circuit breaker should not be used on a DC circuit with a source exceeding 32VDC.